# PTC windchill repository migration to Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, ptc-windchill

I want to shift a repository from PTC windchill to Gitlab. How I can export or download a PTC repository with all history, checkpoint etc.

Comment: What do you mean with PTC windchill repository ? you can customize Windchill adding your own code if needed, but are not suppose to fork/change the code from PTC

Comment: @LoicMouchard The PTC Windchill repository, I need this repo in Gitlab. I can create a Sandbox and upload it into Gitlab. I need the complet repo with checkpoints, history etc. How should I can do this, like we do it with Git.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to import PTC repository into Gitlab. To follow the proper procedure, first the PTC repository Sandbox should be created. The Sandbox should be converted to Git repository via automation and Git repo can be imported into Gitlab.